# How do i dynamically invoke a dll method that receives a callback as parameter?

Tags: c#, reflection, callback, invoke

**Overview:**

I am writting an application to dynamically load .dlls and call their methods.

Since the .dlls are doing heavy i/o in background, i've made callbacks to notify the UI about what's happening "down there"

**Pieces of Code:**

```
            dllName = (string) e.Argument;

            // Assembling Complete path for the .dll file
            completePath       = Path.Combine(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DllsFolder"], dllName);
            Assembly assembler = Assembly.LoadFrom (completePath);

            // Creating Instance of Crawler Object (Dynamically)
            dllWithoutExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension (dllName);
            Type crawlerType    = assembler.GetType (dllWithoutExtension + ".Crawler");
            object  crawlerObj  = assembler.CreateInstance (crawlerType.FullName);

            // Fetching reference to the methods that must be invoked
            MethodInfo crawlMethod       = crawlerType.GetMethod ("StartCrawling");
            MethodInfo setCallbackMethod = crawlerType.GetMethod ("SetCallback");
```

So far, so good.
The problem is that, even tho i have declared the "callback" method

```
public void Notify (string courseName, int subjects, int semesters)
    {
        string course = courseName;
        int a = subjects;
        int b = semesters;
    }
```

This code works (just to test if the callback declaration is working)

```
             Crawler crawler = new Crawler();
             crawler.SetCallback (Notify);
             crawler.StartCrawling();
```

While this, does not work (this is what i am trying to fix. Calling the .dll method dinamically, passing the callback as argument)

```
setCallbackMethod.Invoke(crawlerObj, new object[] { Notify }); // this method fails, bc its a callback parameter
crawlMethod.Invoke(crawlerObj, new object[] {true}    ); // This method works, bc its a bool parameter
```

Comment: You are trying to pass a method, but you can pass only objects. That's reason why passing boolean works. You probably want to use the method as delegate?

Comment: I am trying to invoke(call) a method from a dll, that receives a callback method as parameter.

This is basically what i am trying to do, is there any way i can do it ?
If there is no way, i might have to review the whole app architeture.

Comment: Shouldn't your first `crawlMethod.Invoke(...);` be `setCallbackMethod.Invoke(...);`?

Comment: @MarkM You are right, i was making it wrong,but i just fixed it,and the error message is the same. Thanks for pointing that out btw. I will edit my thread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you have a delegate type like this for passing the method to `SetCallback`:

```
public delegate void CrawlerCallback(string courseName, int subjects, int semesters);
```

Then you may pass the `Notify` method if you cast it to this delegate type like this:

```
setCallbackMethod.Invoke(crawlerObj, new object[] { (CrawlerCallback)Notify });
```

Comment: WOW ! 
Thanks a bunch.
This solved my problem.
Thanks again, really :)