# Notify UI When .dll writes in a file?

Tags: c#, file, user-interface

I've been trying to figure out a way to update the interface after each step my .dll takes, but since there may be multiple .dll's (each one running in a different time) i don't feel like having them so attached to the UI layer.

[This is my lattest thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11037645/how-do-i-dynamically-invoke-a-dll-method-that-receives-a-callback-as-parameter), but the architeture was very confuse, so i removed the notification logic already.

**My Goal:**

1. UI Invokes .dll Dinamically (OK,this works)
2. The .dll ( a crawler, in this case), do its work, and log every step in a file, using a known format. (OK, this is done already)
3. UI Layer, somehow, "knows" or "check periodically" for changes in the file, and parses it in order to display the file content in the user interface (maybe a logbox or w.e)

I am trying to achieve number 3 at the moment, any tips of how to do it without having the .dll too attached / dependant of the interface layer ?

**Questions:**

1. Is there any cons of reading the file within the interface layer in order to have it updated ?
2. Is there any event i may check to handle when the "file changes" or something like that ?
3. If there is no event, can i check asynchronously for the file, to read it,parse it, and show the results in the ui?

What would be the clear/best approach ?

**Observations:**

Using callbacks here is not an option, since i was using it, and because the "depth" of my url layers, firing and throwing events to the upper layer would take me 5-6 layers to reach the user interface itself.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a `FileSystemWatcher` should sort you out

Comment: You were too fast, i can't even accept your answer yet. But i will do in 7 minutes.

Thanks,this looks like what i need